# Axios store same information inside foreach

Tags: vue.js, foreach, vuejs2, axios, mapping

I have an array of objects that is needed to be store in DB when clicking on a single button. Therefore I have used foreach loop and inside the loop, I did the AXIOS POST. AXIOS stores the same information/ object. all objects of the array are not saved is there any solution.

```
let arr = [
            {
              name:'abc',
              co: 1
            },
            {
              name:'def',
              co: 2
            },
            {
              name:'ghi',
              co: 3
            },
         ];
```

```
    let fd = new FormData();
    arr..forEach((element) => {
          fd.append("name", element.name);
          fd.append("co", element.co);

    this.$http.post("po", fd, { headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
           },
          .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data);
           })
          .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
          });
    });
```

WHEN MAPPING THE ARRAY as follows. an error occurs `cannot read property co of undefined`

```
let element=  this.formList.map((obj) => obj);
// appending data
// axios POST
```

**IT ONLY SAVES THE LAST OBJECT. WHAT I WANT IS EACH OBJECT SHOULD BE STORE**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mistake I did was putting the Axios inside the foreach, which overwrites the object each time it loops therefore only the last item gets stored. the working solution is below

```
save() {
  this.StoreMulti(this.arr, 0);
}

StoreMulti(arr, i){
 this.$http.post("po", fd, { headers: {
   "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
  .then((res) => {
        if (i < arr.length - 1) {
            this.StoreMulti(arr, ++i);
        }
       onsole.log(res.data);
   })
   .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
   });
}
```

**THIS STORE THE ENTIRE ARRAY BY SENDING POST REQUEST ONE BY ONE**